# Neo 2.0.1 Becomes Unreponsive

Tags: neo4j

We are using Neo 2.0.1 and are having some problems. After running for several hours (seemingly without issue) Neo becomes unresponsive. It seems to allow incoming requests, but simply doesn't respond, causing these connections to build up in number. A quick look at two jstack dumps from the last two incidents seems to indicate that most threads have become blocked while trying to create transactions. After the first crash, we thought we may have had an issue with our sendmail queues filing up. We emptied the queues and freed up the associated space, but that didn't seem to resolve the issue (the issue arose again in seemingly the same way). Watching things through Visual VM seems to show normal behavior until suddenly CPU and memory seem to flatten out and the server becomes unresponsive. Has anyone else dealt with anything similar using Neo4J and what steps have you taken to resolve? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here are the top couple stack frames from the thread that appears to be the lead block:

```
"qtp1947705168-6665" prio=10 tid=0x0000000018a37000 nid=0x368b waiting for monitor entry [0x0000000046b84000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.expandBricks(PersistenceWindowPool.java:595)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000005990ccbb0> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.acquire(PersistenceWindowPool.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.acquireWindow(CommonAbstractStore.java:431)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NodeStore.updateRecord(NodeStore.java:189)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.Command$NodeCommand.execute(Command.java:397)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.executeCreated(NeoStoreTransaction.java:995)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.applyCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:804)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.doCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:752)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commitWriteTx(XaResourceManager.java:579)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commit(XaResourceManager.java:490)
        - locked <0x000000059e3b05a8> (a org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceHelpImpl.commit(XaResourceHelpImpl.java:64)
```

The lock on the XaResourceManager is what is blocking all our other threads on createTransaction.  The lock on PersistenceWindowPool just hangs around for hours until we restart Neo.  Because of the reference count-based locking there, we can't easily see what specific locks are keeping expandBricks in its loop.

**EDIT**

Heap Configuration

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=10240
wrapper.java.maxmemory=10240
```

Some additional memory config

```
wrapper.java.additional=-Xmn900m
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:SurvivorRatio=1
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:PermSize=512m
```

MMIO Configuration

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=384M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=9336M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=10360M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=16M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=3840M
```

Comment: Is there anything in your logfiles like graph.db/messages.log or data/log/console.log ? Try to enable garbage collector logging in neo4j-wrapper.conf and check the generated files. How do you use your server? Which endpoints do you use?

Comment: @MichaelHunger - There appears to be nothing of interest in console.log, messages.log, or in our gc logs (we already have them enabled). We use the REST API and are exclusively doing Cypher queries. We're not using the transactional endpoint.  Looking into the jstack dump more, we're seeing that the lead block is in expandBricks in PersistenceWindowPool (line 595). Will edit the question to add that.

Comment: Are you running on Windows? And what is your Neo4j heap config and mmio config? Best share graph.db/messsages.log for it contains the diagnostics information.

Comment: @MichaelHunger - We are running Centos 5.6 (Final) (Linux 2.6.18-238.19.1.el5.centos.plusxen x86_64). I'm going to share heap and mmio config by editing the question. I think I will have to email the messages.log (it's a 1 MB zip). Let me know what is the best way to get that to you.

Comment: @MichaelHunger - The issues seems to be related to mmio settings. We commented out the mmio settings we had (as posted in above edit) and were able to run under similar load w/o problem for over 24 hours (no problems ever arose - we stopped Neo manually to test other scenarios). We also used the default settings that are commented out in config file for mmio and saw the same behavior as with the mmio settings posted in question above (however it took a little bit longer to become unresponsive).

Comment: @MichaelHunger - We are still trying to figure out why this is the case, have you come across this before or know of any reason mmio settings would be causing this. If you have any insight we would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: michael at neotechnology.com

Comment: @MichaelHunger - just emailed you the messages.log files.

Comment: @MichaelHunger - just emailed you thread dumps as well. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelHunger - we have been running Neo 2.0.1 instance w/o issue for about a week and a half. This instance has all mmio settings commented out. I'm not sure if I informed you that even when we used the default mmio settings that are initially commented out in config it would still tip over (just take a bit longer 15-30 minutes).